# Time interval between actions within a group in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with users, risk level, and timestamp of that risk. It looks like this:

| user | risk | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | high | 2022-01-01 |
| Jim | low | 2022-01-02 |
| Bob | low | 2022-01-03 |
| Bob | high | 2022-01-05 |
| Bob | low | 2022-01-07 |
| Kev | high | 2022-01-08 |
| Kev | low | 2022-01-10 |
| Kev | high | 2022-01-15 |
| Kev | low | 2022-01-23 |

I want to find how long it takes for a user to go from `high` risk to `low`, so it would look something like this:

| user | high_timestamp | low_timestamp | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 1 day |
| Bob | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-07 | 2 day |
| Kev | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-10 | 2 day |
| Kev | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-23 | 8 day |

Comment: Look for transitions with `lag(risk) over (partition by user order by timestamp)`

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with window functions and `FILTER`, but the way with the least code would be to do something like:

```
SELECT
    "user",
    timestamp AS high_timestamp,
    (SELECT timestamp AS prior_high_timestamp
     FROM t highs
     WHERE highs."user"=t.user AND highs.event='high' AND highs.time<t.time
     ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM t
WHERE risk='low';
```

If performance is a concern I might test different options, however.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is close but doesn't seem to cover the case where a single user goes back and forth between high and low risk, such as user "Kev" in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` to get user rows with `high` value in `risk` column not followed by `low` value at all. It would be like:

```
SELECT 
   high."user",
   high.timestamp as high_timestamp, 
   low.timestamp as low_timestamp,
   CAST(low.timestamp - high.timestamp AS TEXT) || ' day' as duration
FROM user_risk high
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        "user", 
        timestamp
    FROM user_risk 
    WHERE risk = 'low' AND "user" = high."user" AND timestamp >= high.timestamp
    ORDER BY timestamp
    LIMIT 1
) low ON TRUE
WHERE risk = 'high'
```

Please, check working demo at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gRhrkRrvLfBvYGXFAVU7Vc/1.

I've added one more row at the end `('Kev', 'high', '2022-01-25')`, that is not followed by `low` risk value to demonstrate the case